# Socket programing Permission denied

Tags: c, sockets

Following code is TCP server program just send back “HELLO!!” to client.

When I run server with port 80, bind() is returned `Permission denied`.

Port 12345 is OK.

How can I use port 80 for this server program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int
main(){
    int sock0;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    int len;
    int sock;
    char *message;
    message = "HELLO !!";
    sock0 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1",&addr,sizeof(addr));
    bind(sock0,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr));
    perror("bind");
    len = sizeof(client);
    sock = accept(sock0,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&len);
    perror("accept");
    write(sock,message,sizeof(message));
    perror("write");
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ports below 1024 are considered "privileged" and can only be bound to with an equally privileged user (read: **root**).

Anything above and including 1024 is "free to use" by anyone.

OT: you may know this already, but the port in your example is that for HTTP web servers. Anything listening to this port *should* speak HTTP, too. A simple "hello world" does not suffice. ;-)

Comment: @user1345414 Of course it works for root, that's the most privileged user you're going to find. That doesn't mean it's the right thing to do, though.

Comment: @unwind what is the right thing to do .Do you have another solution?

Comment: @user1345414 Don't use port 80 unless you intend to write a (more or less) general-purpose public-facing web server. That's what the port is reserved for, and that's why it requires privileged access to use it since otherwise it would be easier to create security problems.

Comment: I don’t use port 80 for public. I only use it for my understanding of socket programming in private network.

Answer (score 12):

Only the root user is allowed to bind to ports <= 1024. Every ports > 1024 can be bound to by normal users.

Try executing your program as root or with `sudo`.

Answer (score 5):

you have to run your application with super user account (root)

Run your application with `sudo` command