# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied - Spotipy

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to call the Spotify API using the Spotipy Python library. I'm getting a `'PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied'` error.

I'm using a GCP Compute Engine with Debian as the OS.

Error is below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module><br>
  File "/home/#####/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 1307, in current_use
r_recently_played<br>
    before=before,<br>
  File "/home/#####/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 291, in _get<br>
    return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)<br>
  File "/home/#####/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 221, in _internal_ca
ll<br>
    headers = self._auth_headers()<br>
  File "/home/#####/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/client.py", line 212, in _auth_header
s<br>
    token = self.auth_manager.get_access_token(as_dict=False)<br>
  File "/home/#####/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 484, in get_access_t
oken<br>
    "code": code or self.get_auth_response(),<br>
  File "/home/#####/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 439, in get_auth_res
ponse<br>
    return self._get_auth_response_local_server(redirect_port)<br>
  File "/home/#####/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 405, in _get_auth_re
sponse_local_server<br>
    server = start_local_http_server(redirect_port)<br>
  File "/home/#####/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 1227, in start_local
_http_server<br>
    server = HTTPServer(("127.0.0.1", port), handler)<br>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__<br>
    self.server_bind()<br>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/server.py", line 137, in server_bind<br>
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)<br>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind<br>
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)<br>
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied<br>
```

Code example is

```
import spotipy 
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

scope = 'user-read-recently-played'

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope))

played = sp.current_user_recently_played()
```

I have done `chmod 0775 -R` on what I believe are the relevant directories but still getting stuck.

Comment: Have you correctly registered for a developer account and gotten the requisite key(s)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Socket programing Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396820/socket-programing-permission-denied)

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Yes, it did! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying using a different approach. Here's what I use for my Spotify pipeline:

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
import os

un = os.environ['un']
scope = 'user-read-recently-played'
cid = os.environ['cid']
csid = os.environ['csid']
redr = r'http://localhost:8888/callback/'

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(un,scope,cid,csid,redr)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
results = sp.current_user_recently_played()
```

Where `un` is my username, `cid` and `csid` are the key/secret key for my developer account, and redr is just a local webpage for redirects.

Comment: No, unfortunately. I still get the same error at the token = util... line